# How to create route with hyphen from page name in nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I wanted to have route like `privacy-policy` or `terms-condition` in nuxt without having the page name like`Privacy-Policy` or `Terms-Condition` . Is there a simple way to do that without customizing the route or  anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have a page that is called `BoringPage.vue` but want something more fancy, you could write this

```html
<router>
{
  alias: [
    '/cool-page',
  ]
}
</router>

<template>
...
</template>
```

and have access to the `BoringPage` via `/cool-page`.

All you need to do, is to install the [router-extras](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) module.

Answer (score 0):

Create file `_slug.vue` in `pages` directory

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ this.slug }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ params }) {
      const slug = params.slug // When calling /privacy-policy the slug will be "privacy-policy"
      return { slug }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Nuxt dynamic pages: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/pages#dynamic-pages